# Example of a martingale with conditions

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

I'm going through Klenke's textbook (Ex  11.2.1) and there's an exercise asking to think of a martingale (which is nonnegative) $M$ where $\mathbb{E}(M_n) = 1,  \forall n \in \mathbb N$ where $\lim_{n\to \infty} M_n =0$ almost surely.

How would i approach this type of question and think of an example? I can't seem to think of one with these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known example. Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and define $M_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$. You can show that this is  martingale with the desired properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot - but my question was more to do with using the above conditions to construct a martingale rather than given a martingale show these conditions are true... i'm not sure the one you showed seems too intuitive to think of off the top of my head?